# Salesforce as identity provider - SAML authentication request fails

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm trying to do a login using Salesforce as IDP. I have the certificate uploaded in setup->apps->connected apps->manage connected apps
I have also checked "Verify request signature". The strange thing about it is that logout seems to be working, however login response from Salesforce has status "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:AuthnFailed". In logs I see error "Error: Invalid Signature". I'm pretty sure I use same certificate to sign the request to the one that is uploaded to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved, I had to manually specify an algorithm used to sign the request, in my case it was RSA

Comment: This review comment makes no sense.